# Find the canonical decomposition $X$

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me with this question, I don't know how to deal with a metric different than Euclidean.

What is the $\operatorname{Int}A$, $\operatorname{Ext}A$ and $\operatorname{Fr}A$?

$X=\mathbb{R}$, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: This is the Euclidean metric, so you should have no problem then.

Comment: Presumably, Int A means the "interior of A", Ext the exterior, and Fr the border.  Is this correct?

Comment: You should try to used tex typesetting to make your questions easier to read and to understand.

Answer (score 1):

$Int(A) = \varnothing$, $Fra(A) = [0,1]$ as $Adh(A) = [0,1]$ and $Ext(A)$, the extorior of $A$, is equal to $\mathbf{R} \backslash Adh(A)$, that is, to $\mathbf{R} \backslash [0,1]$.

Comment: thank you I understand thanks to you

Comment: what if our metric be post office metric (d(x,y)=|x|+|y|) ?

Comment: Then the results change. Indeed, for this metric, $x$ and $y$ are close if and only each of them is close to zero, which shows that the topology generated by the post-office is not the same as the classic one on $\mathbf{R}$ (for which points far away from $0$ can nevertheless be close), generated by the archimedean absolute value.

Comment: Can you say what is the canonical decomposition of above question when our metric is post office metric? with A=Q rational

Comment: I won't, I'm leaving this to the conscientious OP, that is, to you. ;-)